# Counta Formula Currently Counts One Thing, Want To Add a Condition

Tags: google-sheets

My Formual currently counts the amount of times one word, out of 3 options of a dropdown, is selcted in one column, but I only want it to count it if it has certain text(a name), in another cell on the same row.

My 3 formulas for counting. I only want them to count if the text in column C contains "Alex". I've tried using array and everything but I've scrapped it all as I can't get it to work.

`=COUNTA(IFERROR( FILTER( 'Case Logger'!E:E , SEARCH( "Website" , 'Case Logger'!E:E ) ) ) )`

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR( FILTER( 'Case Logger'!E:E , SEARCH( "Database" , 'Case Logger'!E:E ) ) ) )
```

`=COUNTA(IFERROR( FILTER( 'Case Logger'!E:E , SEARCH( "Tags" , 'Case Logger'!E:E ) ) ) )`

Comment: Figured it out using this formula =COUNTIFS('Case Logger'!C6:C1075,"Brandon Little" , 'Case Logger'!E6:E1075, "Tags")

Answer (score 1):

## Formula

Try something like the following:

```
=COUNTIFS(C:C,"*Alex*",E:E,"*Website*")
```

## Explanation

- COUNTIFS does what you are looking for in a simpler way.
- The asterisk (`*`) is a wildcard. The asterisk enclosed text tells that that the text could appear on any part of the cell value.

## References

[COUNTIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550?hl=en)